# Sinking opponent's ball

Tags: rules, pool

In 8-ball, if you sink the opponent's ball while sinking your own, do you keep playing, hand over play, or is it considered a foul?

Comment: Are you referring to American 8-ball or English 8-ball Pool? They are different games with different foul shot rules.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm just a casual player.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are [multiple sets of rules for 8-ball](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3818/1723).

Comment: @gdrt: I can't see anything about sources in the SE guidelines - where is that mentioned?

Comment: @Mitch, [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) it's said that: *links to external resources are encouraged*. I just thought that it's redundant, cause anyway we always ask people to answer with sources, especially when the question has the *rules* tag. But if you like the previous version, you can, of course, rollback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you have not committed a standard foul otherwise, sinking the opponent's ball is not a foul in itself, so my interpretation of it is that you can continue with the game as you would have normally.

The following is an excerpt from [World Pool-Billiards Association rulebook for 8-ball](http://wpapool.com/rules-of-play/#39Standard-Fouls):

> **3.9 Standard Fouls**  If the shooter commits a foul, play passes to his opponent. The cue ball is in hand, and the incoming player may place
> it anywhere on the playing surface. (See 1.5 Cue Ball in Hand.)
>
> The following are standard fouls at eight ball:
>
> 6.1 Cue Ball Scratch or off the Table
>
> 6.2 Wrong Ball First The first ball contacted by the cue ball on each shot must belong to the shooter’s group, except when the table is
> open. (See 3.4 Open Table / Choosing Groups).
>
> 6.3 No Rail after Contact
>
> 6.4 No Foot on Floor
>
> 6.5 Ball Driven off the Table (See 3.7 Spotting Balls.)
>
> 6.6 Touched Ball
>
> 6.7 Double Hit / Frozen Balls
>
> 6.8 Push Shot
>
> 6.9 Balls Still Moving
>
> 6.10 Bad Cue Ball Placement
>
> 6.11 Bad Play from Behind the Head String
>
> 6.12 Cue Stick on the Table
>
> 6.13 Playing out of Turn
>
> 6.14 Three Consecutive Fouls
>
> 6.15 Slow Play
>
> 6.16 Ball Rack Template Foul