# American 8 Ball Pool - Sinking opponent's ball

Tags: pool

On an 8 ball game, I am left with the 8 ball  close to a pocket and the opponent has one ball blocking the pocket to which I am going to play the 8 ball. If I sink the opponents's ball using the 8 ball and make 8 ball in the same pocket in one shot, who wins the table?

Comment: Related: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5161/sinking-opponents-ball

Comment: Thanks @user16112. I have already seen this. It did not have the direct answer and so thought of posting a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a foul to sink an opponent's ball, therefore you would win the table as long as the right pocket is called.