# 8-ball call shot rules when more than one ball is scored

Tags: rules, pool

If a player intends to score more than one ball in a single shot does he/she need to call all the balls he/she wants to score or just one of them?

I.e. I want to score ball 1 and 2 on a single shot, do I need to say I want to score ball 1 on pocket A and ball 2 on pocket B, or can I just call one of them and score both on the same play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the World Pool-Billiard Association rules of 8-Ball, you only call one ball and one pocket on each shot.  As long as that ball falls into that pocket, your turn continues.  If it does not, your turn ends and your opponent takes over.  Any balls that fall into pockets on your shot stay in the pockets.

If you intend to pocket two balls in one shot, you only need to call one for your turn to continue.

Keep in mind that there are [different rules used for different tournaments](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/3922/1723).

From WPA Rules of Play, General Rules, [1.6 Standard Call Shot](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/the_rules_of_play#1.6):

> 1.6 Standard Call Shot
>   In games in which the shooter is required to call shots, the intended ball and pocket must be indicated for each shot if they are not obvious. Details of the shot, such as cushions struck or other balls contacted or pocketed are irrelevant. **Only one ball may be called on each shot.**
>   For a called shot to count, the referee must be satisfied that the intended shot was made, so if there is any chance of confusion, e.g. with bank, combination and similar shots, the shooter should indicate the ball and pocket. If the referee or opponent is unsure of the shot to be played, he may ask for a call.
>   In call shot games, the shooter may choose to call “safety” instead of a ball and pocket, and then play passes to the opponent at the end of the shot. Whether balls are being spotted after safeties depends on the rules of the particular game.

From WPA Rules of Play, Eight Ball, [3.7 Spotting Balls](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=114&pagetype=rules#3.7):

> 3.7 Spotting Balls
>   If the eight ball is pocketed or driven off the table on the break, it will be spotted or the balls will be re-racked. (See 3.3 Break Shot and 1.4 Spotting Balls.) **No other object ball is ever spotted.**