# Who wins if an opponent's last ball is pocketed while pocketing the 8-Ball?

Tags: rules, pool

During a 8 Ball Pool game when I potted the black ball it hit the opponents last Coloured ball and it went into a pocket. Who wins the frame?

Comment: Please specify exactly which set of rules you are playing under; without that it is pretty much impossible for us to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are [multiple official rule books](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3818/1723) for 8-Ball.  However, I believe that [WPA](http://wpapool.com/rules-of-play/), [APA](http://media.poolplayers.com/TMRB/Rules-Booklet-English.pdf), and [VNEA](http://vnea.com/8-ball-rules.aspx) rules all agree on this.

Assuming that the 8-ball pocket was called correctly, and that the 8-Ball was the first ball contacted by the cue ball, and that no other fouls were committed, it doesn't matter that the opponent's ball was struck and pocketed by the 8-ball.  The shooter wins the rack.